# Breeze - How to handle the state of two entities in the same view before save changes call

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs, breeze

I have 3 entities `Project`, `Attachment` and `Messages`. Project can have multiple attachments and messages.

The problem is on the project detail view, I am listing it's messages and it's attachment (if any) or allow user to add new attachment and post new message. Here is a snapshot for my view

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dfddv9oa7wo8rk/view.PNG

As soon as the user Add new attachment, new attachment entity created through the manager and after the file get's uploaded, save changes immediately called to the server. But before the project detail view render I also created a new entity for message which throw validation error when attachment entity created and save changes called and it make sense. So, how would I handle the state of these two entities? Here is my code

Model Classes

Project.cs

```
Public class Project
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required, MaxLength(50)]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [Required, StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Enter {0} between {1} to {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 300)]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [Required, Range(10, 10000)]
            public int Budget { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public DateTime Created { get; set; }

            public ICollection<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Messages> Messages { get; set; }

}
```

Messages.cs

```
 public class Messages
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }
```

Attachment.cs

```
 public class Attachment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller.js

```
 function activate() {

                getNewMessage();
                common.activateController([getProject()], controllerId)
                    .then(function () {

                    });
            }

     function addNewAttachment(file) {

        var attachment = datacontext.createNewAttachment();
        //other stuff

        return datacontext.save()
            .then(function () {


            });
    }



  function getNewMessage() {
            vm.message = datacontext.createNewMessage();
        }
```

datacontext.js

```
  function createNewMessage() {

        return manager.createEntity('Messages');
    }


    function createNewAttachment() {
        return manager.createEntity('Attachment');
    }
```

Comment: is there any relationship between attachment and messages

Comment: No. Each of them have relationship with project

Comment: Projectid is the foreign key for the two tables if you save the message and attachments entity means you need the projectid

Comment: The validation error appear related to the message. Because new message entity get's created and when I call save changes it expects non-nullable message. Could you please read the question again.

Comment: Can you send the 3 entity class files please

Comment: Posted. Please check. Also,Please note that, the validation error appear related to the Text field of a message whenever a new file attach

Comment: Now you remove the getnewmessage function from activate after you attach the file Wat will reflect it and tell

Comment: You note it without the projectid it will show the error u first create entity for project I will send the example

Comment: I want to create new Message entity at the same time because it is needed if user want to send message. If I remove this, it should work I know

Comment: Hi frnd I need the definition of  getProject() where is it...

Comment: @user3398887 Could you please clarify the question a bit?  I can probably help you figure this out but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I have a project detail view like you can see in the screenshot. When that view render I created a new Message Entity which has a required field in it called "Text". One project may have many messages as well as attachments. But I am not creating an attachment entity like message. It will create when user attach a file and immediately called save changes to save file information. But the problem is, the message entity has already been created during the view render, so If I attach a file and save changes get's called, it throws validation error about "Text" field on message entity. Make sense?

Comment: @user3398887 So are you trying to ignore the validation errors on the message so that you can create an attachment object?  If so I will throw up an answer that can do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the attachment whilst not saving the message you can do so like this -

```
function attachOnly(attachment) {
    // Put the attachment in an array to pass to your entity manager
    var entitiesToSave = [attachment];

    // em is your entity manager
    em.saveChanges(entitiesToSave).then(function(saveResult) {
        // save was successful
    }).fail(function (e) {
        // e is any exception that was thrown.
    });
}
```

Essentially this going to call save changes *only* on your attachment object and ignore the validation errors from your message.

Comment: Thanks for this, was battling to find an example of how to save a single record